# Rails Solr Sunspot order by boolean function result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I'm using Sunspot (2.0.0) for Solr in a Rails (3.2.13) app, and I'm indexing an `ad_type` column that I would like to use to order my results such that certain ads get prioritized over others. Ideally, I could do something like:

```
order_by :ad_type, Proc.new{|ad_type| ad_type.in?(PRIORITY_AD_TYPES)}, :desc
```

So that listings whose `ad_type` is in the `PRIORITY_AD_TYPES` array are listed before those whose `ad_type` is not.

I could add another boolean field that is calculated in the same way in the above Proc and sort by that field, but that would require reindexing initially and every time I change the `PRIORITY_AD_TYPES` array. Is there a more dynamic way to do this similar to the non-functional code I have above?